Power BI :: link Google Sheet columns to calendar table
I'm importing a Google Sheet  spreadsheet in Power BI.
This Google Sheet contains the software that we use with the cost we pay for each month and it looks like this:

As you can see from the picture starting from column Y each column represent a month.
I have my calendar table that looks like this:
Calendar = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDARAUTO(),
    "Calendar Year", YEAR ( [Date] ),
    "Month Name", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmmm" ),
    "Month Number", MONTH ( [Date] ),
    "Day", DAY ( [Date] ),
    "Quarter", "Q" & TRUNC ( ( MONTH ( [Date] ) - 1 ) / 3 ) + 1
)

How can I connect the calendar table with each represented month?
Every solution is accepted as long as it works. Even if you think that the spreadsheet should be arranged in a different way, that too is a good answer. As long as it helps me archive my goal (showing licence costs by month).
I ended up all my ideas.

glad to see you again ! always with challenging questions! Is it possible to use Power Query ?

Hi @AmiraBedhiafi, yes, of course

Not familiar with Bi, but I believe it's always a good idea to create a unpivoted table as the initial source.... and then pivot it later if you desire. Long is better than wide
